# Fiddler - letting localhost pass through (not debugging localhost) how?

Tags: localhost, fiddler

I need to use fiddler to block traffic to a site using autoresponder when working with localhost (as localhost). My question is how to make fiddler transparent to localhost traffic. I don't necessarily need the localhost traffic to go through fiddler, I just don't want fiddler to block it.

I did it in the past after some research but unfortunately I can't find the info.

Notes: 
1.the dot solution (adding dot to localhost paths). using http://machinename or 127.0.0.1 are not the right solutions for me. I remember it was something with the fiddler script or settings.
2. Monitor all connections is ticked ( I saw some advice to tick it)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand your question.  With IE, you have to go through special contortions to get http://localhost traffic to even go through Fiddler-- by default, WinINET applications (like IE) will not send localhost-traffic to proxies (like Fiddler).

Even if the traffic does go to Fiddler, Fiddler isn't going to "block" it unless you tell it to.

"Monitor all connections" has no impact here.

Answer (score 0):

Apologize but this [article](http://geeks.netindonesia.net/blogs/zeddy/archive/2009/06/07/using-fiddler-with-localhost-and-force-any-localhost-traffic-to-a-proxy.aspx) is in Indonesian language. Basically you can try to register a custom domain name such as ADomain.xyz.com and associate it with 127.0.0.1 . You can do it through DNS or host file.

Regards,

hadi

Comment: Thanks. I know this technique. I belive there is something that can be done in Fiddler alone to solve my problem.